# Generate single XML file from SQL Server with multiple results per customer

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have a need to send an XML file to a vendor, containing specific data from our SQL Server database.  I know that SQL Server does have integration with XML, but I'm unfamiliar with it, so what I decided to do was simply select the XML tags as concatenated text, with the fields I need in between.  That works, but I then realized that solution won't suit our needs.

The reason is that, for a given customer, it is possible to have multiple results.  And if there are multiple results, since SQL Server returns a separate row for each result, it would generate multiple files per customer as well.  We need a single file for each customer.

This is the piece of the SQL in particular that would generate multiple results per customer:

```
-- Carriage return in variable for repeated use
declare @cr varchar(2) = char(13) + char(10)`

'<activity>' + @cr +
'<activity_date>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) + '</activity_date>' + @cr +
'<activity_desc>' + Term.Code + ' Remaining Balance' + '</activity_desc>' + @cr +
'<charge>' + bal.Balance + '</charge>' + @cr + 
'</activity>'
```

What we need to accomplish is to have the resulting XML output be something like this if there are multiples of the Term.Code field:

```
<activity> 
  <activity_date>02/01/2018</activity_date>
  <activity_desc>WINTER17D     Remaining Balance</activity_desc> 
  <charge>50.00</charge> 
</activity> 
<activity> 
  <activity_date>02/01/2018</activity_date> 
  <activity_desc>SPRING18A    Remaining Balance</activity_desc> 
  <charge>15.00</charge> 
</activity>
<activity> 
  <activity_date>02/01/2018</activity_date> 
  <activity_desc>SPRING18B   Remaining Balance</activity_desc> 
  <charge>20.00</charge> 
</activity>`
```

Three separate `<activity>` tags, all within the same file, but with the rest of the XML having only one tag per customer.  So, the full results would be like this:

```
<Billing> 
<stmt_date>02/01/2018</stmt_date> 
<id>987654</id> 
<total_due>85.00</total_due> 
<name>Test Person</name> 
<message>You have an outstanding balance.</message>
<activity> 
  <activity_date>02/01/2018</activity_date>
  <activity_desc>WINTER17D     Remaining Balance</activity_desc> 
  <charge>50.00</charge> 
</activity>
<activity> 
  <activity_date>02/01/2018</activity_date> 
  <activity_desc>SPRING18A    Remaining Balance</activity_desc> 
  <charge>15.00</charge> 
</activity>
<activity> 
  <activity_date>02/01/2018</activity_date> 
  <activity_desc>SPRING18B   Remaining Balance</activity_desc> 
  <charge>20.00</charge> 
</activity>
</Billing>
```

Is this possible?  Here is the SQL Query we'll use to generate all the raw data set:

```
SELECT  RTRIM(Person.PersonID) AS PersonID,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS StatementDate,    
  bal.Balance,
  RTRIM(Person.StuNum) AS PersonNum,
  RTRIM(Person.Email) AS Email,
  Person.Addr1,
  Term.Code AS Term
FROM   Person(nolock)
  JOIN Enrollment(nolock)
    ON Person.PersonID = Enrollment.PersonID
  JOIN AcctStatus(nolock)
    ON Enrollment.EnrollmentID = AcctStatus.EnrollmentID
       AND AcctStatus.SaAcctStatusID NOT IN(5, 16)
  JOIN
(
   SELECT EnrollmentID,
        TermID,
        CAST(SUM(CASE Type
                   WHEN 'I'
                   THEN Amount
                   WHEN 'D'
                   THEN Amount
                   ELSE Amount * -1
                END) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Balance
   FROM   Ledger
   GROUP BY EnrollmentID,
          TermID
) AS bal
    ON bal.EnrollmentID = Enrollment.EnrollmentID
       AND bal.Balance <> '0.00'
  JOIN Term(nolock)
    ON Term.TermID = bal.TermID
       AND Term.TermID NOT IN(105, 34, 60, 194, 193, 97, 74)
ORDER BY Person.PersonID,
    bal.TermID
```

Comment: This is most certainly possible, though pray and tell me - why are you manually creating the tags for the XML when you can have SQL do it?

Comment: It's new to me...I have no prior experience with XML, aside from a basic understanding of what it's used for. Unfortunately, neither do any of the other SQL developers where I work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major flaws:

- Never create an XML via string concatenation. Just imagine, one of your text columns contains data like `'Do & Co'`. The `&` would break your XML's validity!
- Never use culture depending date formats! I did not know, whether your date values are the second of January or the first of February. Always use a *secure and independant* format such as `ISO8601` (especially within XML)!

Try it like this:

There's a mockup scenario which you'll have to adapt to your needs. The basic idea is to use `FOR XML PATH()` for the billing data and another sub-select - again with `FOR XML PATH(),TYPE` for the related (nested) activities.

```
DECLARE @mockupBilling TABLE(StatementDate DATE, ID INT, Balance DECIMAL(10,4),Name VARCHAR(100),Msg VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockupBilling VALUES(GETDATE(),987654,85.0,'Test Person','You have an outstanding balance.');

DECLARE @mockupActivity TABLE(BillingID INT, ActivityDate DATE, Activity VARCHAR(100), Charge DECIMAL(10,4));
INSERT INTO @mockupActivity VALUES
 (987654,{d'2018-01-02'},'WINTER17D Remaining Balance',50.0)
,(987654,{d'2018-01-03'},'SPRING18A Remaining Balance',15.0);

SELECT b.StatementDate AS [stmt_date]
      ,b.ID AS [id]
      ,b.Balance AS [total_due]
      ,b.Name AS [name]
      ,b.Msg AS [messge]
      ,(
        SELECT a.ActivityDate AS [activity_date]
              ,a.Activity AS [activity_desc]
              ,a.Charge AS [charge]
        FROM @mockupActivity AS a
        WHERE a.BillingID=b.ID
        ORDER BY a.ActivityDate
        FOR XML PATH('activity'),TYPE
       ) 
FROM @mockupBilling AS b
FOR XML PATH('Billing');
```

The result

```
<Billing>
  <stmt_date>2018-02-02</stmt_date>
  <id>987654</id>
  <total_due>85.0000</total_due>
  <name>Test Person</name>
  <messge>You have an outstanding balance.</messge>
  <activity>
    <activity_date>2018-01-02</activity_date>
    <activity_desc>WINTER17D Remaining Balance</activity_desc>
    <charge>50.0000</charge>
  </activity>
  <activity>
    <activity_date>2018-01-03</activity_date>
    <activity_desc>SPRING18A Remaining Balance</activity_desc>
    <charge>15.0000</charge>
  </activity>
</Billing>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to adapt this into something which is closer to what we need. But now here's the tricky part.

This would work if we were sending multiple files with one single customer.  But what we need to do is send one file with ALL customers in it.  Each customer will be separated by the <Billing></Billing> tag.  I didn't mention that originally because I didn't realize how relevant it would be.

Comment: @Shungo Apologies, I didn't realize that pressing enter adds the comment rather than a carriage return.  Updated that comment with details of what's actually tricky.

Comment: I suggest to close this question, as the initial question seems to be solved. Then start a new question, use my *mockup* scenario, add tables and test data and the expected output to it. Then place a link here (or there) and help will rush in very soon :-D

Comment: Will do!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer would be to use a regular select statement for your query, though add `FOR XML PATH('ACTIVITY')` into there.
I would love to help you with this, though you haven't provided a complete query to work with. Add that, and then myself or others can guide you along.

> Read up on`FOR XML` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server

Comment: Updated the question with the SQL.  However, as you can see, it won't return the additional tags (ex. <Billing> and <Activity>), just the data that would be used.  I assume an update might be necessary for that?

Comment: @DillonP seems as if Shnugo beat me to it here... the way to create a nested set of tags is to use a set of nested queries - please see his answer for details - no point in me recreating it here.